# Cumulative number of events weighted by temporal aggregation

Tags: r, time-series, aggregation

I would like to use the cumulative number of events that occurred during 10 consecutive years weighted (measured once a year) by their temporal aggregation as an explanatory variable in my analysis. I hypothesize that consecutive event occurrence has a higher effect on response variable compared to events scattered in time. 
What are the methods/approaches that would allow me to do this type of analysis?

Thank you.
Marina

Comment: this might be an interesting and rather unusual question if you provide more detail. First, why cumulative, if what you are intersted in is the frequency and number of events per 'cluster' (or else give more detail on the design). How many observations of response variable/yr/temporal cluster?

Comment: I have only one observation of response variable. Let me explain my research question in a bit more detail. I am working with ecological data, trying to test for an effect of an invasive insect on plant abundance. The insect defoliates the forest, and there're data on annual occurrence and severity (2 categories) of defoliation. I have a number of sites for each I collected historical defoliation data (10 years) as well as data on plant abundance measured at one time point (after 10 years). I also have reference plots with no defoliation history.

Comment: Instead of simply summing up the cumulative occurrence x severity across 10 years, I am trying to come up with some more ecologically realistic measure that takes into account how defoliation events are distributed in time. For example, 3 defoliation events separated with 2 years with no defoliation most likely have a smaller effect than 3 events in a row.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest scenario, you could use maximum number of consecutive events and/or the number of consecutive defoliation events preceding the response variable (plant abundance) measurement. Which can then be used in e.g. a multiple regression with total N of events, cumulative severity, and max N of consecutive events. This would capture the amplitude and frequency of defoliation. In a way, measuring abundance in a single, terminal time point already narrows the question to cumulative effects (vs. e.g. periodicity of the predictor and response variables). However, autocorrelative structure of defoliation events may be of interest in itself, and could be examined separately, and may provide additional insight into other aspects of this relationship you may wish to consider.